# Setup DNS record with mail and web server on different IP but with the same domain

Tags: dns, dns-servers, mx

I got my webserver where my website is hosted and my mail server on two different servers with different IPs.

I would like to have mail email `@example.com` using the mail server
I have used an A record on my DNS for `example.com` to point to my web host IP and an MX record for `example.com` that points directly to the mail server IP.

Now, pointing directly the MX record to an IP is not the best option as intoDNS reports

> MX is not IP  ERROR: Some of your MX records returned by your
>   nameservers are IP addresses. This is not ok per the RFCs and you
>   should change them.

I would like to create an MX record that points to a domain for my email IP address but, at the same time, I would like to keep using `example.com` for the emails, even if the mail server is on a different IP.

How should I set up the DNS records?

Comment: By design of the DNS, the "target" of an `MX` record can only be an hostname, not an IP address. Just put the A record to the IP of the website, do an `MX` record to `mail.example.com` and add an `A` record for that name to the IP address of your mail hosting server.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek this should be an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 5):

By design of the DNS, the "target" of an `MX` record can only be an hostname, not an IP address.

Just put the `A` record for `example.com` to the IP of the website, do an `MX` record to `mail.example.com` and add an `A` record for that name to the IP address of your mail hosting server.